# Query which should return the non existing values in table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have

- A list of Primary keys(around 10).
- A table has 100 rows.

Lets say among 10 keys which I have, if there are 8 keys found in the table.

I need the output of the remaining 2 keys which is not present in the table.

Eg: i have 10 empl id's which i need to query in Empl table.
Empl table has 100 or even more rows. Among 10 empl id which i have , only 8 are there in empl table. I need to get that remaining 2 empl ids which are not there in empl table.
NOTE: if you use not in , it will give all other empl ids from empl table. But i need only those two which are not present.

Comment: Hello welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
 [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) with a schema and some data so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
 much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: A SQLFiddle is not necessary. better encourage to put all info directly into the question than on another site. An **additinal** fiddle is fine though.

Comment: @juergend Maybe isnt necesary but for new users I like to introduce to SqlFiddle and the proper way of asking a question. Also if you read `SQL` tag a `sqlFiddle` is already recommended even when will be outside.

Comment: But since SQLFiddle breaks all the time it is best to remind users not to forget to put also everything into the question. Otherwise the question is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the query a little shorter I give you an example for 3 keys you have to check in a table

```
select k.*
from
(
  select 1 as pk
  union all
  select 3
  union all
  select 7
) k
left join your_table t on t.id = k.pk
where t.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where my_key not in (select distinct my_key from the_other_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table10 T
WHERE not exists ( SELECT 1
                   FROM Table100 Q
                   WHERE T.ID = Q.ID )
```